# Binding an ICommand to a MenuItem and assign a ShortCut

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have the following scenario:

A ViewModel with multiple ICommand (RelayCommand) properties. Those properties are bound to menuitems in the view. Some of the menuitems should have a keyboard-shortcut. To do this I've tried using InputBindings of the window. This works - but I have to assign the InputGestureText manually to the MenuItem. So I guess theres a better way to bind a ICommand to a MenuItem and assign a shortcut...

```
// ViewModel
class MyViewModel: ViewModelBase {
    public ICommand TestCommand {get; set;}
}

// View
<Window...>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Key="R" Modifiers="Control" />
    </Window.InputBindings>

    // ...
    <MenuItem Name="MenuItemTest" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
              Header="Test" InputGestureText="Ctrl + R" />

</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InputGestureText` property is just used to set a text that *describes* an input gesture that will call the command associated to the command.

It does *not* associate the input gesture with the menu item somehow; it simply adds text to the menu item. This is documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext(v=vs.110).aspx.

So no, there is no better way of doing what you are doing :)

Comment: This is one of the moments I want to go back to WinForms :/

Comment: Why? Since assigning a shortcut to a MenuItem in WinForms displays the assigned shortcut - and i dont have to assign a text :) And about the missing upvote: Please don't get me wrong, you answered my question and I accepted your answer. But you just confirmed that I am doing it right and there is no other way so you did not provide a 'solution' to my problem. But I'll vote your answer...

Answer (score 0):

May be I am a bit late, but:

Automatic shortcut hinting on menu items works with `RoutedCommand`.

```
public static readonly RoutedUICommand NewProject = new RoutedUICommand() { InputGestures = { new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control) } };
```

If you do so - you will get your hotkey working (even without input binding in window) and you will see this hotkey in any menu item bound to this command. This will work only with `RoutedCommand` (type is hardcoded in WPF source). If your command is not `RoutedCommand` (and it isn't, as you use `ICommand` pattern) - you *have to* set gesture hints by your own.

So there are two options: use `RoutedCommand` and event handlers for them (in UI code!) or implement your own commands and do whatever you can with shortcut hints.